# Need to create the custom OAuth 2.0

Tags: c#, oauth, oauth-2.0

I need to create the sample application by **accessing the `OAuth`** 2.0 provided networks(Google, Facebook, Instagram, etc...) data.

Can you please **suggest me to the common way** to achieve those all networks implementing with OAuth2.0 support.

Please share the Common Authorization getting the process and Access token getting process (or) share any custom OAuth projects for this.